# rest api for UPDATE in azure functions using python

Tags: python, azure, function, put

I want to update the cosmos db through the update api in python using azure functions.
How to get the rest api for UPDATE in azure functions using python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed requests through pip and imported it to your machine?

Assuming i've understood your question right,
You should then be able to push the requests through using:

```
requests.put('https://<your cosmos db link here>', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Alternately microsoft itself has some helpful documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-04-01-preview/database-accounts/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/)

Comment: @KajalBalchandani This is the example based on whats on the microsoft page,  but without knowing what you're aiming to do it's hard to say:

`import requests requests.put(https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/{accountName}, data = {key:value})
`

Comment: I don't have a link i'm afraid, just what I wrote in the comment as any code would be specific to what you're working on